# How to select $(this) children div?

Tags: jquery, ajax

this is an AJAX post. There are a group of buttons, I add a div#message after every button.

I want that when the user clicks each button, the word hello will show in each div#message.
How to add a $(this), before div#message'?

JS:

```
success: function(){
    $('#message').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $('#message').html("hello");
    })
    $('#message').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('#message').html('');
    })
```

CSS:

```
#message{display:none;float:right}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='post'><a href="" class="ajaxpost" id="'.row['id'].'" name="ajaxpost">'.row['title'].'</a><div id="message"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
$(this).children('div#message')
```

If you also want to search descendants, call `find` instead of `children`.

However, it won't actually work.
Inside the `success` callback, `this` will not refer to your element.
You can change that by passing `context: this` in the AJAX parameters, or by setting a variable in the outer function to `this` and using that instead.

---

However, you should not be doing this in the first place.
IDs should be unique.
If you will have multiple `div#message`s in different blocks, you should use `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: How to  passing `context: this` in the AJAX parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Adding multiple div's with the same ID is a bad idea. Use classes instead.

You can do the following query:

`$('.message',this).fadeIn(...`

Answer (score 0):

In my case `children(...)` didn't work properly.

> If you also want to search descendants, call find instead of children.

So in my case only `find(.class_name)` works properly